# Eclipse file template plugin doesn't use my template file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I am not really familliar with this topic but I want to create a plugin described at this page:

[HowTo extend CDT with custom file templates](https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_extend_CDT_with_custom_file_templates).

So far as described in the Link I got it working. But in the example the template format is directly described in the `<template>...</template>`-Node:

```
// ${file_name}
// Test Source
```

But what I want to do is not to write my file template format into the XML-File of the plugin. Instead I want to have a file that is used with the file temlate, in my example `H_Template.h`. But I don't know how to include that file. Does anyone know?

I tried to use the attribute `<include file="H_Template.h"/>` with an relative path to the file from my plugin location. Or is it the relative path to my eclipse folder?

template.xml:

```
<templates>
   <template name="Source template" 
     id="test.codetemplates.csourcefile" 
     description=" " 
     context="org.eclipse.cdt.core.cSource.contenttype_context" 
     enabled="true">
     // ${file_name}
     // Test Source
   </template>
   <template name="Header template" 
     id="test.codetemplates.headerfile" 
     description=" " 
     context="org.eclipse.cdt.core.cHeader.contenttype_context" 
     enabled="true">
     <include file="H_Template.h"/>     <!-- <<<<<<<< ??? -->
   </template>
 </templates>
```

H_Template.h:

```
// ${file_name}
// Test Header
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this. The template code must be included as part of the template.xml file.

The Eclipse code which reads the template is `org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.persistence.TemplateReaderWriter`.